# Is it necessary to return `404 Not Found` when trying to delete the resource?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I'm thinking about if it's necessary to return the `User doesn't exist` message with the `404` status code when the client is trying to delete the user.

- If we're going to delete the user anyway, what's the point to return the `User doesn't exist` message?
- If we want to know the user does exist or not, we'll use `GET` method instead of the `DELETE` method right? If the user doesn't even exist **before**, then it won't be displayed on the list, how would you wanted to delete it?
- Let's say I opened two tabs on my browser, then I deleted the user in the first tab, now I'm trying to delete the same user in the second tab, should I get `200 OK` status or `404 Not Found`?

The user doesn't exist anymore, isn't this what I wanted? Shouldn't it be an `OK` for me?

Comment: If your delete operation goes through successfully, then it is best that you return the status code as OK, meaning your operation was successful.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, when you try to `GET` a resource that doesn't exist, you should return 404 (along with a message if you want).

When you try to `DELETE` a resource, the intent being "this resource should not exist after this call", you should always return a 2XX code (204 if there is no content – the general case –, or 200/202 are the options you have). The fact that the resource is already deleted or has never existed doesn't conflict with the intent, so there's no use to return 404.

Hope this helps.